# MVC-4 site.css VS CSS from scratch?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm a beginner with MVC4. Is it worth spending time on learning how the site.css is structured? How can I render HTML from my views that the site.css picks up?

Or would it be easier for me to just make my own CSS and use my own HTML for all my views and totally ditch all the pre-generated layouts.

What MVC features do I miss out on if I decide to go all with my own CSS and HTML coding? Or is it a bad idea to start with?

Answer (score 1):

CSS only controls how the page appears, you will not lose any MVC features if you decide to build your own CSS.

You might lose some features when you change the HTML, if you're not paying attention. For example, the validation summary won't be rendered if you get rid of the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` statement from your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, I would advise editing the current site.css with your own styles...no need to create a new one..by adding and changing the existing one, you can see how it is working.

And once you change it enough, it will have become your own version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly should use your own HTML and CSS, rather than trying to make existing samples work for you.  It is a template, a guide, to give you an example project and I think it should be used just for that.

Create your basic HTML markup and look into how you can use the html helpers that MVC provide in your markup.  Doing it this way we give you a much greater understand of how the MVC framework works.

There are plenty of good examples out there, don't worry if they are MVC3, they are still relevant.  Here are a couple of links to get you started.

[MVC4 Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-4-Sample-37924d68)

[MVC3 Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)